# Unitary transformation to make diagonal elements zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, unitary-matrices

For arbitrary $A\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$, is it always possible to find a unitary matrix $Q$ such that $QA$ has zero diagonals? Namely, to make $QA$ in the following form:
$$
QA=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
    x_{21} & 0 & x_{23}\\
    x_{31} & x_{32} & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Here is my thought: In QR factorization, we apply a sequence of unitary matrices to $A$ to produce more and more zero elements. For example, using Givens rotation, we introduce 1 zero each time, while using Householder we introduce a column of zeros each time. For the current problem, we can always apply Givens rotation to make the 1st and 2nd diagonals zero, i.e., $\exists Q' s.t.$
$$
Q'A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
    x_{21} & 0 & x_{23}\\
    x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, I could not prove, neither disprove, that we can also make the 3rd diagonal zero.

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr}$.  Then all columns of $QA$ are equal.  In order for the diagonal elements to be $0$, we'd need $QA = 0$.  But obviously this can't happen for a unitary matrix $Q$.

Comment: Very nice counter example. Thanks.